# Searching through a particular Property within an array of Objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I used to have this array in my user schema, referencing a course:

```
courses: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Course",
    },
  ],
```

When I wanted to find all the course data of the different courses a particular user is subscribed to, i used to do this:

```
return Course.find({ _id: { $in: user.courses } })
```

Now I'd like to save when the user signed up for each course, but I'm a bit stuck here.

I thought I could just change it to this:

```
courses: [
{
  courseRef: { // <==== Now it's not an array of refs, but an array of objects & each objects holds a reference to a course
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Course",
  },
  startDate: { type: Date, default: null },
},
```

],

However, now `return Course.find({ _id: { $in: user.courses } })` does not work anymore, since the array doesn't hold those refs but a property inside each object of the array does.

A few hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
return Course.find({ _id: {$elemMatch: { $in: user.courses }},startDate:{$gt:new Date('date')} })
```

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't I need to specify somewhere that I'm looking for the `startDate` field?

Comment: I don't understand. Do I need to replace anything in your answer? I get `"ISODate is not defined`

Comment: if you want to check another field put it like startDate , so replace date object with `ISODate`

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.